# Xcode 7 beta 5 Swift 2 redundant conformance to protocol error

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I recently download Xcode 7 which comes with Swift 2. Below is the error I get when I try to conform my class to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` which works perfectly well in Xcode 6.2 but throws an error in Xcode 7 beta 5

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

> //error: Redundant conformance of 'TableViewcontroller' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

I have searched google for answers but I couldn't get a fix for it.

Comment: `UITableViewController` already conforms to the two protocols. No need to specify it again.

Comment: really? so i should skip that i get on with my project. Thanks a bunch man

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no need to indicate that you `TableViewController` conforms to the two protocols because the `UITableViewController` already does. So your class will as well due to the inheritance.

All you need is:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
}
```

It seems Swift2 is more strict about this than Swift is.

Comment: This is a little annoying when you want to extract your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` into separate protocol extensions in your `UITableViewController` class for organization purposes.

Comment: @CraigOtis Yes Same i want do but getting redundant conformance error. Can you help to extract?

Comment: @PinankLakhani You should open a separate question.