# UITableViewController shows nothing but horizontal lines

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just starting with Swift and xCode, and currently messing around with UITableView, I can't manage to just write 'test' into a table.

I created a `UITableViewController` in the Storyboard, specified a custom class for it (my swift file below), filled in 'ClientCell' as a reuse identifier of the cell and the code is as follows:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


  @IBOutlet var clientTable: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      clientTable.dataSource = self.dataSource;
      clientTable.delegate = self;
  }

  func numberOfRowsInSection(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.tableLabel.text = "test"

        return cell
    }
}
```

In the storyboard, I added a 'UILabel' into the prototype cell, and created an outlet for it named 'tableLabel' in the CustomTableViewCell.swift.
I confused by all the side-things I've to consider when doing something as simple as this.
When I run it, the simulator just shows a table with a lot of horizontal lines, but nowhere it says 'test'.

Comment: You are writing your tableview data source methods inside of your viewDidLoad() override. There's no way that will ever work. Move numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath into a class extension and declare them outside any other function bodies.

Comment: @Dare With into a class extension, you mean right before the viewDidLoad()?

Comment: No, this is what I mean. https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#protocol-conformance

Comment: @Dare I'm not sure if that works with a UITableViewController the same way. I'm getting: _Redundant conformance of 'TableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'_

Comment: No need to conform to the delegate and datasource again. Just extend the class. It will work even without an extension. But you cannot conform to a protocol inside of viewDidLoad(). It has to be a class level declaration not inside of that function body.

Comment: @Dare Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but according to this, that is not needed and therefore gives the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163313/xcode-7-beta-5-swift-2-redundant-conformance-to-protocol-error

Comment: There was an edit to fix the scoping since you originally posted. Make sure your code matches the post after Almas's changes

Comment: @Dare I'm sorry for those endless comments, but it is the same and it shows the same error. The code I have now after your suggestions: http://pastebin.com/iaaqAALT

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used the numberOfRowsInSection method.....
Additionally you also need to set the table view's data source and delegate to be the class you are writing these methods in (in case you haven't).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I updated my code and also edited it here. However, I still have the same issue. Am I assuming correctly that datasource and delegate are both self?

Comment: They are unless you set them otherwise.  It's also possible that the auto-layout of your prototype cell is wrong, so the text isn't visible.

Comment: You can also try having a look at the views that are made in the app. When running the app in the simulator, you can debug the view heirarchy and determining if the cell is being made. If it is, you should have a look at your constraints.

Comment: What constraints do you suggest? A horizontal one only didn't do the trick.

Comment: You need to set enough constraints for the view to know its x and y position inside its superview. At the very least you should add the vertically in center constraint to the label and assign a leading value to it.

Comment: @IrLearn Still doesn't show. I'm not sure if it's even created. However, there is no error.

Comment: Replace your method with this and see if it shows up:override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ClientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
        return cell
    }

Answer (score 0):

At a bare minimum you need this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 // this should really be from your data source
}
```

If you create a `UITableViewController` subclass in Xcode the template will have commented-out versions of all the methods you likely will want to fill out.

Comment: Isn't that already done by the last method in my code above? I'm getting an error there.

Comment: @FelixF. No that's not done by the last method. The last method is how you customize each cell as it loads. numberOfRowsInSection will return how many cells appear in your table. Without that, you will see 0 cells appear